Return functions with different signatures from other function with correct typing
In my code I have a dispatch function that takes one parameter and returns another function depending on the parameter, something like this:
type Reason = 'create' | 'delete';

function dispatch(reason: Reason) {
    switch(reason) {
        case 'create':
        return createInternal;
        case 'delete':
        return deleteInternal;
    }
}

function createInternal(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
}

function deleteInternal(code: number) {
    console.log(code);
}

Now this initially worked, since my returned functions had the same signature. After adding another function with a different signature, I realised that this has an issue. The return type of the 'dispatch' function is a union of all possibly returned functions.
The following usage is now not possible anymore, since typescript can't infer the correct type of the returned function.
dispatch('create')('123'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
dispatch('delete')(123); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Is there a way to fix this, or alternatively implement a better dispatch function that doesn't have this issue?
Here's a link to a playground.
Edit
I have found half a solution with the help of generics. Now I can correctly call the dispatched function, but I get further errors inside the dispatch function that I don't understand.
Playground
type Reason = 'create' | 'delete';
type DispatchedFunction<T extends Reason> = T extends 'create' ? typeof createInternal : typeof deleteInternal;

function dispatch<R extends Reason>(reason: R): DispatchedFunction<R> {
    switch(reason) {
        case 'create':
        // Type '(name: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'DispatchedFunction<R>'.
        return createInternal;
        case 'delete':
        // Type '(code: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'DispatchedFunction<R>'.
        return deleteInternal;
    }
    return () => {} // I had to add this so the function doesn't return undefined
}


You could create a constant lookup object and just index into that:
type Reason = 'create' | 'delete';

const DispatchFunctions = {
    'create': createInternal,
    'delete': deleteInternal,
} as const;

function dispatch<R extends Reason>(reason: R): typeof DispatchFunctions[R] {
    return DispatchFunctions[reason];
}

function createInternal(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
}

function deleteInternal(code: number) {
    console.log(code);
}

dispatch('create')('123');
dispatch('delete')(123);

The same approach works when converting Reason to an enum:
enum Reason {
    CREATE = 'create',
    DELETE = 'delete',
}

const DispatchFunctions = {
    [Reason.CREATE]: createInternal,
    [Reason.DELETE]: deleteInternal,
} as const;

function dispatch<R extends Reason>(reason: R): typeof DispatchFunctions[R] {
    return DispatchFunctions[reason];
}

function createInternal(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
}

function deleteInternal(code: number) {
    console.log(code);
}

dispatch(Reason.CREATE)('123');
dispatch(Reason.DELETE)(123);


Thanks, I like that. Contrary to the actual question, how could I make this work with Reason being an enum instead of a type? I wasn't able to use it that way.

I think that typescript is little bit confused there, and you need to explicitly cast return to that generic type
        case 'create':
        return createInternal as DispatchedFunction<R>;
        case 'delete':
        return deleteInternal as DispatchedFunction<R>;



Thanks, I did that now. Definitely better than @ts-ignore.

No problem, but if you dont mind creating object with that functions, i consider solution by Robby Cornelissen better

here is how I would implement it,
type Reason = 'create' | 'delete';

function dispatch(reason: Reason):(args:any)=> any {
    switch(reason) {
        case 'create':
        return createInternal;
        case 'delete':
        return deleteInternal;
    }
}



Thanks, this would be my fallback solution, since unfortunately I then lose type safety.
